# permanently change /tmp stickbit to -t

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, tmp

I want to change the stickbit permision of `/tmp` directory to `-t`.

The problem is every time I reboot the permissions reset to 1777. How can I permanently change the `/tmp` directory to 0777 ?

I have root permission to handle the `init.d` configuration, but I also need some guidance. My OS is Ubuntu Server 16.04.

```
zeusbase@tiuque:/$ ls -la /
...
drwxrwxrwt   8 root root     4096 sep 27 09:20 tmp
....
```

Comment: There are easier ways to break your system.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: why don't you just answer the fking question you fks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is by design, the `/tmp` is a place where anyone can put (temporary) files, and only that user can remove/rename the file (the sticky bit is for this exact purpose).

Do not change it, as it is used by many programs to keep data and would lead to a unstable condition if you remove the sticky bit and for some reason (e.g. unintentional deletion, bug) the file(s) from `/tmp` gets removed.

Note that, on some systems `/tmp` is `tmpfs` (resides in memory), on some systems it is part of `/` (disk backed). On Ubuntu desktop, it is disk backed, and if you remove the sticky bit on it, you won't be able to initiate a session next time.